# How to use Google Maven Dependency in android projects?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio-2.2

How should i change build.gradle and other files in android projects to add dependencies offline?
I downloaded Google Maven Dependency from developer.android.com but i don't know how should i use it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation covers very useful topics, including the one you're asking about.

```
dependencies {
    // Dependency on a local library module
    implementation(project(":mylibrary"))

    // Dependency on local binaries
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
}
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies